# Unity - Testing Facebook SDK Not Showing in Facebook

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm testing the example scenes that get added when adding the Facebook SDK to our Unity game.

Testing each of these methods succeed and return a post id, however, the post, photo and shared link never show up on my users Facebook page.

Our user is a normal Facebook account that has been invited as a Tester of our app.

The user has granted gaming_profile and gaming_user_picture permissions.

```
            if (this.Button("Share - Link"))
            {
                FB.ShareLink(new Uri("https://developers.facebook.com/"), callback: this.HandleResult);
            }

            // Note: Web dialog doesn't support photo urls.
            if (this.Button("Share - Link Photo"))
            {
                FB.ShareLink(
                    new Uri("https://developers.facebook.com/"),
                    "Link Share",
                    "Look I'm sharing a link",
                    new Uri("http://i.imgur.com/j4M7vCO.jpg"),
                    callback: this.HandleResult);
            }

            this.LabelAndTextField("Link", ref this.shareLink);
            this.LabelAndTextField("Title", ref this.shareTitle);
            this.LabelAndTextField("Description", ref this.shareDescription);
            this.LabelAndTextField("Image", ref this.shareImage);
            if (this.Button("Share - Custom"))
            {
                FB.ShareLink(
                    new Uri(this.shareLink),
                    this.shareTitle,
                    this.shareDescription,
                    new Uri(this.shareImage),
                    this.HandleResult);
            }

            GUI.enabled = enabled && (!Constants.IsEditor || (Constants.IsEditor && FB.IsLoggedIn));
            if (this.Button("Feed Share - No To"))
            {
                FB.FeedShare(
                    string.Empty,
                    new Uri("https://developers.facebook.com/"),
                    "Test Title",
                    "Test caption",
                    "Test Description",
                    new Uri("http://i.imgur.com/zkYlB.jpg"),
                    string.Empty,
                    this.HandleResult);
            }
```